# How to move mouse by xdotool in all 4 diagonal directions?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, mouse-cursor, xdotools

How to move mouse by `xdotool` to quadrant II or IV of the display?

([What I mean by "quadrants"](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1a/Cartesian_coordinates_2D.svg/800px-Cartesian_coordinates_2D.svg.png).)

Moving mouse by `xdotool` to quadrant I is working fine this way:

```
mousemouve_x=100
mousemouve_y=100
xdotool mousemove_relative -- -$mousemouve_x -$mousemove_y
```

Moving mouse by `xdotool` to quadrant III is working fine this way:

```
mousemouve_x=100
mousemouve_y=100
xdotool mousemove_relative $mousemove_x $mousemove_y
```

How to move mouse by `xdotool` to quadrant II or IV direction of the display?

Remark:

- After trying a little bit its looks its clear for me how to do. THX especialy to Kamil Maciorowski:
- The follow "mousemove_relative -- x100 y100" accept for x and y positive and negative counts. The follow "mousemove_relative x100 y100" accept positive and negative counts for y.
- A negative x value give bak a error message, a positive value working fine. Thats looks for one of than like a small bug of xdotools. If anybody know how to report this bug, pls report the small xdotools bug.

Answer (score 0):

The quadrants from mathematics do not exactly apply here because in computer graphics and display the Y coordinate almost always grows from top (of image or screen) to bottom. In math the phrases "X is increasing and Y is increasing" and "moving towards upper-right" are usually equivalent(ish), in computers they are usually not.

You could see the difference if your commands actually worked. There are typos (`mousemouve` vs `mousemove`), there are unquoted variables that may expand to nothing. In a fresh shell neither command moves the cursor diagonally. If they work (or ever worked) for you then maybe because there are (or have been) non-empty variables with names containing `mousemove` declared *earlier*.

To be clear: these are your commands fixed (i.e. without typos):

```
mousemove_x=100
mousemove_y=100
xdotool mousemove_relative -- "-$mousemove_x" "-$mousemove_y"
```

```
mousemove_x=100
mousemove_y=100
xdotool mousemove_relative -- "$mousemove_x" "$mousemove_y"
```

They work and move the cursor along one of the diagonal directions. I understand your question is: how to move the cursor along the other diagonal direction?

When you run something in a shell, you provide zero or more arguments as *character strings*. The tool may interpret some of them as numbers. Here `xdotool mousemove_relative --` expects two arguments in a certain format, so it can interpret them as numbers. A string that looks like a positive number will cause the respective coordinate to increase (if possible); a string that looks like a negative number will cause the respective coordinate to decrease (if possible).

In your (fixed) try you make strings passed to `xdotool` look like positive numbers by just expanding the variables whose values themselves look like positive numbers (`100`). And then you make strings passed to the other `xdotool` look like negative numbers by prefixing `-` characters to expanded values that look like positive numbers.

To move the cursor along the other diagonal direction you need one string to be interpreted as a negative number, the other as a positive number:

```
# poor code though
mousemove_x=100
mousemove_y=100
xdotool mousemove_relative -- "$mousemove_x" "-$mousemove_y"
```

or

```
# still poor code
mousemove_x=100
mousemove_y=100
xdotool mousemove_relative -- "-$mousemove_x" "$mousemove_y"
```

I called this "poor code" because it's **conceptually wrong**.

Conceptually this is *data*:

```
mousemove_x=100
mousemove_y=100
```

and this is *code*:

```
xdotool mousemove_relative -- "-$mousemove_x" "$mousemove_y"
```

Up to this point we were choosing direction by changing code. The right way it to change the data:

```
mousemove_x=100
mousemove_y=100
xdotool mousemove_relative -- "$mousemove_x" "$mousemove_y"
```

```
mousemove_x=-100
mousemove_y=100
xdotool mousemove_relative -- "$mousemove_x" "$mousemove_y"
```

```
mousemove_x=-100
mousemove_y=-100
xdotool mousemove_relative -- "$mousemove_x" "$mousemove_y"
```

```
mousemove_x=100
mousemove_y=-100
xdotool mousemove_relative -- "$mousemove_x" "$mousemove_y"
```

Note the code is the same in all four cases, it's universal. You can get any possible movement just by supplying the right data.

Code that uses e.g. `-$mousemove_x` is not universal because you cannot pass a string that looks like a positive number this way. If you try to reverse the direction by storing `-100` in the variable then you will end up with `--100`; this will not be interpreted as a positive number.

Comment: * After trying a little bit its looks its clear for me how to do. THX:
 * The follow "mousemove_relative -- x100 y100" accept for x and y positive and negative counts. The follow "mousemove_relative x100 y100" accept positive and negative counts for y. 
* A negative x value give bak a error message, a positive value working fine. Thats looks for one of than like a small bug of xdotools. If anybody know how to report this bug, pls report the small xdotools bug.

Comment: @Alfred.37 Two things: (1) [What does `--` (double-dash) mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11376/108618) (2) [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: I tryed to vote your post positive. A its only possible for me after my 15. question on superuser.com.